# Restore 'cd ..' functionality after following a symbolic link

Tags: command-line, directory, symbolic-link

If I create a symbolic link in the terminal with a command like

`ln -s /path/to/some/directory symbolicLink`

and then follow the link with

`cd symbolicLink`

the terminal appears to think that the cwd is `~/symbolicLink/` even though it is actually showing `~/path/to/some/directory/` (assuming that the link was made in `~`, of course). What this means is that if I then type `cd ..` I am taken back to `~`, because the terminal 'thinks' this is the parent of the cwd.

What would I need to change such that `cd ..` would instead take me to `~/path/to/some/`, i.e. the *real* parent of `~/path/to/some/directory/`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456784/behavior-of-cd-bash-on-symbolic-links.

You can use 'cd -P' to go to the "real" parent directory.
See the first comment on the top answer on how to make this the default behavior.

Answer (score 5):

There's a subtle caveat in the `cd -P` behaviour (posted as answer because of the length):

```
$ dir1=$(mktemp --directory)
$ dir2=$(mktemp --directory)
$ ln -s -- "$dir1" /tmp/start
$ ln -s -- "$dir2" "$dir1"
$ cd "/tmp/start/"*
$ cd -P ..
```

What should `pwd` print now? Logically, it could be either

1. `$dir1`, if `cd -P ..` does `cd ..` first and `cd -- "$(readlink -f)"` afterwards, or
2. `/tmp`, if `cd -P ..` does `cd -- "$(readlink -f)"` first and `cd ..` afterwards.

In fact it does the latter, meaning that `pwd` is intuitively *two* levels higher than the "parent" directory.

Comment: Thanks! `cd -P` still solves the issue I was facing, but is still useful to know.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way is to run:

```
cd $(/bin/pwd)/..
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel your pain—I consider `bash` to be basically broken for interactive use because of this behavior.

`tcsh` is a far more user-friendly shell for interactive use.  Leave `bash` for programming (if you insist on writing shell scripts when there are much better alternatives among the many scripting languages).

To change shells for any user, type `chsh` at the command line and follow the prompts (again, I recommend `/bin/tcsh` and the excellent O'Reilly book [*Using csh and tcsh*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565921320.do), available for next to nothing used).

Comment: Since I wrote this answer, I've learned to stop worrying and love Bash for interactive use.  But I still can't deal with the default `cd` behavior for symlinks.  I have to remember to put `set -o physical` in my `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` for every machine I use.